# How to run pry on Debian Linux for ARM

Tags: pi-2, linux, arm, ruby

I installed rvm and Ruby 1.9.3p194 on a Raspberry Pi using Debian Linux.  When I installed pry using `gem install pry`, everything installed perfectly but typing pry in a terminal didn't work:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ pry
bash: pry: command not found
```

there's a pry file in `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin`.  I have to call it with ruby_noexec_wrapper in the same directory:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/pry
/usr/bin/env: ruby_noexec_wrapper: No such file or directory
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ cd .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin
pi@raspberrypi ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin $ ./ruby_noexec_wrapper pry
[1] pry(main)>
```

What's the proper way to run pry in this Linux?  On Windows and Mac OS X I can simply type pry at any command prompt or terminal.

***UPDATE***: Here's my `rvm info`:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin $ rvm info

ruby-1.9.3-p194:

  system:
    uname:       "Linux raspberrypi 3.1.9+ #168 PREEMPT Sat Jul 14 18:56:31 BST 2012 armv6l GNU/Linux"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.2.20(1)-release (arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf)"
    zsh:         " => not installed"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.14.10 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "1 day 23 hours 36 minutes 30 seconds ago"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "1.9.3p194"
    date:         "2012-04-20"
    platform:     "armv6l-linux-eabi"
    patchlevel:   "2012-04-20 revision 35410"
    full_version: "ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [armv6l-linux-eabi]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194"
    ruby:         "/home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/home/pi/.rvm/bin:/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libfm:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games"
    GEM_HOME:     "/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194"
    GEM_PATH:     "/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194:/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194"
    IRBRC:        "/home/pi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> gem install pry

If you want to include the `bin` directory used by `gem`, you will need to add it to [your `$PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)).

`bin` directories generally contain executables and if you `echo $PATH` you'll see a number of them there.

If you had installed `pry` from the distro package, `apt install pry`, then likely it would be in a normal system `bin`.  However, the distro version (0.10) is probably older than the one installed by `gem`, and will not get updated as often (presuming `gem`, or you, update stuff it installs).

To add to `$PATH`:

```
export PATH $HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:$PATH
```

This prefixes that directory.  It is important not to *replace* the rest of it, which is why there's `:$PATH` at the end.

You may prefer to use [a symlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link):

```
ln -s ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin ~/ruby-bin
```

And use that (`~/ruby-bin`) in `$PATH` for brevity and to blackbox the current version string.

To make it permanent, put that `export` command in `~/.profile`.  Note that it applies only to the current shell session, so if you have added it in one GUI terminal it won't magically apply to a concurrent one.  Also note that `.profile` may not be run if you use a GUI login.  To check just login again and `echo $PATH`.